# How to protect EXIF data against editing/deleting in jpeg file?

Tags: access-control, file-encryption, protection, file-access

Is there any option to protect EXIF data against editing or provide password protection?
I came accross the idea of creating executable file from  image file, so that someone can view image the way is defined with no possibility to modify. Is this possible? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: If you make your own executable container, consider DMR (Digital Media Rights) protection, which will hide your image from the PrintScreen feature and various screen recording software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXIF data is metadata. Basically any (unencrypted) metadata can be altered anytime with access to (a copy of) the file.

*Your idea of creating an executable to open images and protect EXIF data seems a bit like building a underground bunker just for storing the labels on and tabs in a physical folder.*

Apart from the practical problems like system rights for running executables, possible antivirus detection, compatibility problems. You'll probably also get around this protection by screen capturing techniques like screenshots, screen recording and making actual photo's of the screen with another device. Or printing and rescanning it.

Secondly, the standardised metadata (EXIF) will be useless (for other applications and OS) when you put it in an executable container.

*Why and in what environment would you possibly like to protect EXIF data? Maybe log it and monitor for changes in it?*

Comment: This concept came accross the course I was attending and I started to think about some solutions that can secure EXIF data. I'm a begginer, so sorry for imprecise question. I was just wondering if it's possible to secure, protect original exif data in some way against modification later. The idea with own executable was soultion I encounter during digginig.

Comment: @rocksparrow It's always possible to protect everything, but the same applies for breaking it ;). It's an endless cat and mouse game. Can you close the answer by choosing it if you consider it answered?